# Allocating memory for a self-referential structure in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to use malloc to allocate memory for a couple of structures. I've done my research but haven't been able to find anything that's helped me. Here are the structures:

```
typedef struct _square
{
    char figure;
    int num_neighbors;
    struct _square *neighbors[7];
} point;

typedef struct_plot
{
    int num_squares;
    struct _square *dots;
} plot;
```

The pointer *dots should point to the first element of the array of pointers to squares (*neighbors[7]) and the value of num_squares is the input to the function.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
Here's what I've been trying:

```
plot* plot_create(int size)
{
    plot *newPlot;
    square * square_neighbors[8];
    if((newPlot = (plot *)malloc(sizeof(plot))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation error");
        return NULL;
    }

    if((square_neighbors = (node *)malloc(size*sizeof(square))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation error 2");
        return NULL;
    }
    return newPlot;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please post your attempt and what you think is wrong.

Comment: Note: You have a typo in typedef struct_plot - it should be typedef struct _plot.

Comment: Why only 7 neighbours for a square?  Normally, people would assume 8 or 4 (depending on whether diagonals count or not).

Comment: @Jonathan The OP also uses `square_neighbors[8]`. The very first thing that should be taught (drummed into heads) in programming classes is the importance of encapsulation, with manifest constants as a basic example.

Answer (score 1):

> The pointer *dots should point to the first element of the array of
>   pointers to squares (*neighbors[7])

No it shouldn't ... the type of a pointer to the first element of neighbors is `struct _square **`, not `struct _square *`.

In your EDIT, you cast the result of `malloc` to `(node *)`, which is not a declared type, and then you attempt to assign it to `square_neighbors`, which is an array and cannot be assigned to. And it's an array of 8 `square*`, but there's no such type declared. And after assigning it to that local variable, you return without using the value, leaking memory. Also in your original code you have `typedef struct_plot` which is a typo.

Please, before posting a question to SO, run your code through the compiler and fix the typos and other errors and warnings that it reports. Once you have done that we can try to address your conceptual errors.

Answer (score 1):

### Pointer Arrays

This should clarify what it is you're trying to do.  In the code below we first allocate an array of 8 pointers to point objects (struct _squares).  We then allocate memory for each point object and initialize them as needed.

You can access this data structure as shown.  Note that this does not necessarily allocate memory contiguously (since multiple calls to malloc are made).

### Sample Program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _square
{
    char figure;
    int num_neighbors;
    struct _square *neighbors[7];
} point;

typedef struct _plot
{
    int num_squares;
    struct _square *dots;
} plot;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    point** residents = malloc(8 * sizeof(point*));
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        residents[i] = malloc(sizeof(point));
    }
    residents[0]->figure = 'A';
    residents[1]->figure = 'B';

    residents[0]->neighbors[0] = residents[1];
    printf("First neighbor of %c is %c\n",
        residents[0]->figure,
        residents[0]->neighbors[0]->figure);

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
First neighbor of A is B
```

Comment: You allocate room for 8 residents but only set 7 of them, and the OP's code also uses the constants 7 and 8. Professionals use manifest constants. Also you don't make any use of the plot structure ... that's important because the OP says that `dots` should point to to the first element of `neighbors`, but that's a type mismatch. Also, `typedef struct _square { ... } point` is pointlessly confusing. And professionals don't use `struct _square` declarations when there is a typedef available ... start off with `typedef struct Square Square;` (not needed in C++) and then just use `Square`.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm just replying to the OP using his code.  Agreed on using named constants.  I'll update the answer to fix that.  The typedefs are taken directly from the OP's question...

Comment: I don't see an edit. And this is a teaching site, where the person asking the question is often a very confused beginner ... copying their mistakes "directly" is generally a bad idea.